# ReactJS/Javascript: Render graph when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs

All the graph example I have looked at automatically renders a graph with auto generated data. The app I am working on will be passed parameters from a frontend UI and submit a query to the backend DB using those parameters.  Then, I want to use the results from the query to populate a graph function.  I am working on the code for the graph function using a separate class/component. But everytime I make a change to my code I get error messages because it wants to populate a graph with no data. So, how do I call the graph component, which is outside of the submit button class, when the button is clicked?

Comment: you can hide the graph component till the time you dont have data , show it once you have the data . use react conditonal redering to hide and show.

Comment: you you are looking for any code help , please post you code here .